# Implementing Bluetooth data transfer on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

How can I create a Bluetooth application for the iPhone? What do I need to know about controllers? Delegate methods?

Comment: The simulator does not have bluetooth support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GameKit` framework contains APIs to allow communications over a Bluetooth network. Using these `APIs`, you can create peer-to-peer games and applications with ease.All the various APIs for accessing the Bluetooth is located in the `GameKit framework`.

Here is good example code in  [this...](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502/1954) link

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, link-only answers are generally discouraged on Stack Exchange sites. The reasons for this are described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116301/131713) and at several other posts. Usually I just flag these and mods delete them, but I see you've been active recently, so I thought I'd give you a chance to update this (and possibly earn some rep!) first.

Comment: @LordTorgamus : thanks for your guidance. I really appreciate your guidance...actually I didn't aware of it.But I have seen many answer with link only so I did.Now, this answer is already accepted so how can I update it ?

Comment: You can always edit your own posts, whether they're accepted or not. The "edit" link is near the bottom left corner of the answer. For me, on this post, it's under the word "should." Just explain the part of the link that answers the question, or even copy it if that's allowed by the original site, and leave the link as a reference/support. Thanks!