# How to get the mobile number of the iPhone using Bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, sony-smartwatch

I would like to forward the caller mobile number to a bluetooth device (which is similar to 
meta watch where the mobile number is visible on the smart watch and bluetooth device is non ios device)

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/metawatch-manager-for-ios/id557219641?mt=8

Above link mentions about caller id notifications.

Before asking this question I had gone through the following links.

[How to get user incoming call phone number in iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681449/how-to-get-user-incoming-call-phone-number-in-ios-device?rq=1)

[Getting mobile number from log to the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255267/getting-mobile-number-from-log-to-the-app?rq=1)

[How to get the Phone number from the callID(call Identifier) of call which returned form callcenter in iphone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297206/how-to-get-the-phone-number-from-the-callidcall-identifier-of-call-which-retur?rq=1)

The answer for all of the questions is not possible.I think there should be some way to get the mobile number of the caller using bluetooth. Any suggestions or any pointers. Is it possible do to this using MFi Or Any other ways to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

The Bluetooth accessory can get the mobile number of the caller in various ways. Most straightforward:

- If your Bluetooth accessory uses LE: implement a client for iOS' Apple Notification Center Service (ANCS), which is a GATT server that comes with iOS 7 and later. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html
- If your Bluetooth accessory uses BR/EDR: implement the "Hands-free unit" side of the Hands Free Profile (HFP). iOS has shipped since long with the "Audio Gateway" side of this profile. See https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/HFP.aspx

Also see Apple's Bluetooth Developer page, which is a good starting point for more info: https://developer.apple.com/bluetooth/

Answer (score -1):

there are couple of ways of doing it.

1 > whenever a call comes, stream the info through bluetooth serial port profile to the remote bluetooth device [assuming remote device support bluetooth serial port profile]

2> Depending on the bluetooth capability of the remote device[profiles support], you can decide on which profiles you need to use to transfer data.

Direct Answer to your question:
   Could not give a direct answer, because the capability of remote bluetooth device is not clear.

The following link may help you in understanding more about bluetooth interaction in iPhone

[Implementing Bluetooth data transfer on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706954/implementing-bluetooth-data-transfer-on-the-iphone)

Comment: Mount Mani:Thanks for quick reply,I have this in mind,but my question is how will I get the Caller information from iPhone ? And one mre thing the links you have gives insight into gamekit ,but I have to use Core Bluetooth or EAAcessory to communicate with Bluetooth device

Comment: I think I mis understood your question. I tried to give answer on transferring information thru bluetooth. "I think there should be some way to get the mobile number of the caller using bluetooth".

Comment: On retrieving the caller ID, I dont know .

Comment: Caller ID wont work Check this link                                                               How to get the Phone number from the callID(call Identifier) of call which returned form callcenter in iphone sdk?